# MySQL IF THEN ELSE

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to make a `IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT` statement but I get errors around the `UPDATE` line. I could do this in two separate queries but I'm not sure what would be better.

I've tried to follow this guide but didn't manage to make my query work. https://blog.udemy.com/sql-if-then/

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM `table`
    WHERE
        `column` = 'value'
)
THEN
(
    UPDATE `table` SET
        `date` = NOW()
    WHERE
        `column` = 'value'
)
ELSE
(
    INSERT INTO `table` SET
        `date` = NOW(),
        `column` = 'value'
)
END IF
END
```

Comment: MySQL is not a programming language like C or Java. That being said, you can write a procedure or function. Where are you executing this "code" at the moment?

Comment: Server runs `PHP`.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I'm not sure your comment is constructive. `IF` statements are quite common in SQL. `INSERT`/`UPDATE` are common as well. It is just that I can't figure how to write mine.

Comment: Are u going to insert/update in single query if record exists, Right? If yes, refer this link [insert/update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: @HarshalY: I do not have keys in my table so I cannot use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: It might have been more constructive had you answered the carefully-composed question I embedded within it, instead of just complaining. Oh well, good luck.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition no need to down vote the question just because I don't get the value of your comment. As for you question, I do not know what you mean by "where".

The question remain unanswered but I have solved my problem by running two queries. One to find out if the entry exists. Based on the result I either update either insert.

Comment: _"no need to down vote the question just because I don't get the value of your comment"_ I didn't. Don't cast aspersions.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

In your case "column" would be a unique key

Comment: I do not have any (`PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`) keys set. To know the values of the keys would mean to have the `SELECT` query separately. Edit: I will consider setting `UNIQUE` on `column`.

Comment: My columns are `TINYTEXT` so I cannot use them as keys.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to use TINYTEXT rather than VARCHAR(255)? VARCHAR is ISO standard and as it is stored as part of the row (unlike TINYTEXT) it doesn't have the extra memory overhead.

Comment: Not really. I'll look into it and will consider converting the columns.